# Managed Object Structure in IOS, what is correct design with NSManagedObjects used as class members?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

just a quick one. I am making a data object which contains many subclasses. All of which are just Data Containers.

I am using the managed object context, and I was curious whether I should make every subclass inherit from the NSManagedObject, or does only my root class need to.

Reason I ask is that I have in my AppDelegate, a blank copy of this root object initialised at startup to be used as a temporary one during a Setup Wizard style set of forms. After each step, I create one of the subclass objects and populate its class members with data from the form, before moving to the next form.

Now, on submit on form 1, I am creating the subclass fine, but if I try to set the field of the root class back in the app delegate, I get a memory exception.

I am saving basic details about a car, to an overall list of details about a cars settings (like what tyres it has).

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.tempSetup.car = theCar;
```

And also

```
        [appDelegate.tempSetup setCar:theCar];
```

Error given is `[SetupSheet setCar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` which I assume is something to do with perhaps the pointer to the 'theCar' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to figure something out on my own for a change :)

What I did was:

- Go back into the Data Model, and make sure my Entitys were as desired.
- Created the "New Files" based on the Data Model in the New File Wizard.
- In my App Delegate, create an instance of the SetupSheet object and add it to the `ManagedObjectContext`.
- Within the SetupSheet, I overrode the `awakeAfterInsert()` function to create new objects of each subclass that is being stored in the SetupSheet.
- Finally, at the end of the `awakeAfterInsert()` function, I assign these new objects to the class fields of the SetupSheet.

I set a breakpoint after the Insert Into Context call in AppDelegate and did a printout of the SetupSheet object, and sure enough all the fields are displayed as nil (As they are not set) but the memory locations of all the subclasses are created and valid.

Remember to delete your app from your Simulator or Device after any changes to the models.